# loop over characters in string, Common Lisp

Tags: string, common-lisp

How would I loop over the characters in a string of text in Common-lisp?

Here's what I want to do, but in Ruby:

```
string = "bacon"

string.each_char do |c|

    putc c

end
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
(map nil #'princ "bacon")
```

or

```
(loop for c across "bacon" do (princ c))
```

Answer (score 3):

Looping over a string can be done using `loop` like so:

```
(let ((string "bacon")) 

   (loop for idex from 0 to (- (length string)) 1)
      do 
         (princ (string (aref string idex)) ) ))

;=> bacon
;=> NIL
```

To gather up the characters in `string` as a list use `collect` in the loop instead of `do` like so:

```
(let ((string "bacon")) 

   (loop for idex from 0 to (- (length string)) 1)
      collect 
         (princ (string (aref string idex)) ) ))

;=> bacon
;=> ("b" "a" "c" "o" "n")
```

Comment: you could also use `print` instead of `princ`

Comment: You don`t need to subtract 1 from the length. Use `BELOW`.
You actually don't need an index in LOOP to iterate over a string at all. Use `ACROSS`. Also converting a character to a string does not make sense. `PRINC` can print characters. Thus `STRING` is a waste. You can also use `WRITE-CHAR`, which is slightly more low-level. `("b" "a" "c" "o" "n")` is also not a list of characters. It is a list of strings.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I don't think that I ever said that it returned a list of *characters*--I said that it gathered up the characters in a *list*, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it stored them *as* characters.  I just meant that they were processed individually.